# Angular with ES6 Controller As Behaving Strangely

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6, static-methods, angularjs-controlleras

That's a bad title. I'm aware. That's because I'm not entirely sure how to ask this question. I've got two essentially identical classes, behaving just a **little** bit differently, a corresponding `controllerAs: 'vm'` in the state config for each of them also behaving differently and a perplexing "this method can be static" warning from Webstorm in one of them and not the other.

**index.html**:

```
<div ui-view="main"></div>
<div ui-view="portfolio"></div>
```

**app.js**

```
// this file contains only the module setter with all the
// dependencies, as well as the $stateProvider config and
// any actions that occur when the app runs

'use strict';

angular.module('necApp', ['dep1', 'dep2', 'etc'])

    .config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', '$animateProvider', Config])
    .run(['$rootScope', '$state', Run]);

function Config(params) { /* do stuff */ }
function Run(params) { /* do stuff */ }
```

**main.js**

```
use strict';

import { MainController } from './main.controller';

angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('MainController', MainController)
    .config(['$stateProvider', Config]);

function Config($stateProvider)
{
    $stateProvider

    .state('main',
    {
        url: '/',
        views: {
            'main': {
                templateUrl: 'app/main/main.html',
                // OF NOTE: I have access to the controller as 'vm' in the view
                // regardless of whether I include the next two lines
                controller: MainController,
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            }
        }

    });
}
```

**main.html**

```
<!-- 
     again, this expression is evaluated whether or not I include
     the `controller` and `controllerAs` properties in my $state config 
-->
<h1> {{ vm.result }} </h1>
```

**main.controller.js**

```
// OF NOTE: when I DO include the `controller` property in the $state config
// for the main route, this controller is registered and instantiated twice
'use strict';

export class MainController
{
    constructor($http)
    {
        /* @ngInject */
        angular.extend(this, {
            $http: $http,
            result: ''
        });

        this.Init();
    }

    Init()
    {
        this.$http.get('/endpoint').then(res =>
        {
            this.result = res.data;
        });
    }
}
```

**portfolio.js**

```
use strict';

import { PortfolioController } from './portfolio.controller';

angular.module('necApp')
    .controller('PortfolioController', PortfolioController)
    .config(['$stateProvider', Config]);

function Config($stateProvider)
{
    $stateProvider

    .state('portfolio',
    {
        url: '/portfolio',
        views: {
            'portfolio': {
                templateUrl: 'app/portfolio/views/portfolio.html',
                // OF NOTE: I do NOT have access to the controller as 'vm'
                // in the view in this case without the next two lines
                controller: PortfolioController,
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**portfolio.html**

```
<!-- this is NOT evaluated without the `controller` and `controllerAs` properties in the $state config -->
<h1> {{ someExpression }} </h1>
```

**portfolio.controller.js**

```
'use strict';

export class PortfolioController
{
    constructor()
    {
        angular.extend(this, {

            someExpression: 'Testing . . .'
        });

        this.Init();
    }

    // OF NOTE: Webstorm warns me that this method can be static, even though
    // 1) that breaks it and 2) I do NOT get that warning in MainController
    Init()
    {
        // works as expected
        console.log('initializing PortfolioController.');
    }
}
```

As always, I very much look forward to your thoughts and comments.

Comment: I guess every method that doesn't have 'this' in its body will get that warning.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, before anybody else wastes their own valuable time with this, it turns out I'm just dumb. Or forgetful. I found a forgotten and unused directive I wrote that was for some reason using the `MainController` as 'vm'. Geez.

Although: I still have Webstorm warning me that `PortfolioController.Init()` can be static, while I do not get that warning on `MainController.Init()`. So that's still a mystery, I guess.

Comment: I swear I did a project-wide search for 'MainController' before I posted here. I feel like I just drunk-dialed Stackoverflow.